# Fancybox opening issue - works on JSFiddle but not in live environment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm trying to get a fancy box popup opening when the user click on "CONTACT" in the navigation menu. It works on JSFiddle, see http://jsfiddle.net/88X6D/1/ but for some reason it doesn't work in live environment, see http://goo.gl/lkfxeO (nothing happens when clicking on "contact" in the menu)

I initially thought there was a conflict between the "smooth scrolling" script and the "contact form" script but since it works on JSfiddle, the issue must be somewhere else. (also fancybox JS files and jquery are correctly called).

Thanks for your help

HTML

```
<li> <a href="#inline" class="modalbox highlightit">Contact</a>

</li>
```

SCRIPTS (located in this file: js/scripts.js)

```
//==============
//! Smooth scrolling
//==============

$(function () {
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function () {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top - 100
            }, 'normal');
            return false;
        }
    }
});
})

window.onscroll = scrollFunction;
function scrollFunction() {
    var doc = document.documentElement, body = document.body;
    var top = (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0);
    if (top > 200) {
        $('.back-to-top').fadeIn();
    }
    else {
        $('.back-to-top').fadeOut();
    }
}



//==============
//! Contact form
//==============


function validateEmail(email) { 
        var reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return reg.test(email);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".modalbox").fancybox();
        $("#contact").submit(function() { return false; });


        $("#send").on("click", function(){
            var emailval  = $("#email").val();
            var msgval    = $("#msg").val();
            var msglen    = msgval.length;
            var mailvalid = validateEmail(emailval);
            var nameval = $("#name").val();

            if(mailvalid == false) {
                $("#email").addClass("error");
            }
            else if(mailvalid == true){
                $("#email").removeClass("error");
            }

            if(msglen < 4) {
                $("#msg").addClass("error");
            }
            else if(msglen >= 4){
                $("#msg").removeClass("error");
            }

            if(nameval < 2) {
            //name must be at least 2 characters
                    $("#name").addClass("error");
            }
            else if(nameval >= 2){
                    $("#name").removeClass("error");
            }

            if(mailvalid == true && msglen >= 4) {
                // if both validate we attempt to send the e-mail
                // first we hide the submit btn so the user doesnt click twice
                $("#send").replaceWith("<em>sending...</em>");

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '../sendmessage.php',
                    data: $("#contact").serialize(),
                    success: function(data) {
                        if(data == "true") {
                            $("#contact").fadeOut("fast", function(){
                                $(this).before("<p><strong>Success! Your message has been sent, thank you.</strong></p>");
                                setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1000);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Where are you calling `.fancybox()` and performing the fancybox setup (as described in the [Fancybox documentation](http://fancybox.net/howto))?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think your link refers to an old version of fancy box. Anyway, I've added this to my header - without success: <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox();
 });
</script>

Comment: Turns out you do have that line in your source after all - it's in your `$(document).ready() call in the 'contact form' section. Note that you've got to use `.modalbox` instead of `.fancybox` as the selector, as that's your link name. I think the new docs are [here](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#instructions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your click handlers. Your 'contact' link ends up with two handlers:

1. One for scrolling (set up in your `$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click()` call)
2. One for Fancybox (implicitly added by the call to `$('.modalbox').fancybox()`).

The scrolling click handler ends with `return false`. **This stops all later click handlers running**. Thus your scrolling click handler runs, but Fancybox's click handler doesn't - the scrolling click handler told the browser not to.

The scrolling click handler should have an `ev.preventDefault()` call instead. `ev.preventDefault()` stops the browser carrying out the "default" action (in this case, trying to follow the link), but **doesn't prevent later click handlers running**.

Here's an updated scroll handler that should get your Fancybox working:

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function (ev) { // Added 'ev' parameter
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        if (target.length) {
            ev.preventDefault(); // We're animating this, so don't let the browser try to navigate to this URL
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top - 100
            }, 'normal');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Indeed, it fixes the fancy box issue but now the "back to top" button that I have on other pages doesn't work anymore, probably because you removed this: $('.back-to-top').fadeIn();
    }
    else {
        $('.back-to-top').fadeOut();

Comment: I didn't remove that; the code I posted was an updated version of the click handler only. You should leave the rest of your code intact.

Comment: Thanks it works now! Only remaining issue is that scrolling is not very smooth anymore, see http://goo.gl/f0B0Jc when you click on contact or on back to top. Is there a way to add some smoothness to that? Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You're not including the Fancybox script on [your page](http://goo.gl/f0B0Jc). Thus you get an error when the script loads ("undefined is not a function", because `.fancybox` is undefined), and so your smooth scrolling code isn't running at all.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to include  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox();
 }); at the beginning of my scripts.js file. How can you see this error message? When I run the error console on Safari it says that everything is fine. Thanks

Comment: It's not the `$(document).ready()` command you need to include - that sets up the Fancybox, and that's *the equivalent of the error*. In your second page you're not loading the Fancybox script at all; you need to include something like `<script src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>` in your page. I can see the error on both the Firefox and Chrome consoles; I don't have a copy of Safari to hand so I don't know if it's visible there.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but can you check again now http://goo.gl/f0B0Jc I've included the fancy box script, no error on firefox console, but doesn't seem to scroll smoothly (but maybe that's just my impression). Thanks

Comment: Your smooth-scrolling click handlers - the line with the complicated selector in my original response - is outside a `$(document).ready()` call in your second page. Thus, when your script gets run, there's nothing in the DOM for it to attach to. Wrap it in a call to $(document).ready()`.